# Get any item from the Set (Collection)

Tags: java

I will give a simpler example than it actually is: the function should return the max *Integer* of the *Set*.

```
Integer getMax(Set<Integer> set) {

    Integer max = 100;   // ! initial value !

    for(Integer integer : set){
        if(integer>max) {
            max=integer;
        }
    }

    return max;

}
```

In this method, the initial value is 100. I would like the initial value to be selected from the *Set*, so I did this (we assume that the *Set* is not empty):

```
Integer getMax(Set<Integer> set) {

    Integer max = null;
    for(Integer integer : set){  // initial value selection
        max = integer;
        break;
    }


    for(Integer integer : set){
        if(integer>max) {
            max=integer;
        }
    }

    return max;

}
```

This works, but are there any simpler and more effective alternatives (to get any item from the *Set*)?

**P.S.** Finding the maximum value is just an example.

The main problem is **to get any element from the *Set***. I changed the example:

```
Integer getAny(Set<Integer> set) {

    for(Integer integer : set){
        return integer;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: " I would like the initial value to be selected from the Set" <--- why would you want that ?

Comment: How about `Collections.max(set)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first element of the given set you can use:

```
set.iterator().next()
```

So you can do like:

```
Integer getMax(Set<Integer> set) {

    Integer max = set.iterator().next();   //  First element in the set

    for(Integer integer : set){
        if(integer>max) {
            max=integer;
        }
    }

    return max;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Integer getMax(Set<Integer> set) {
    Integer max = null;
    for (Integer integer: set) {
        if (max == null || integer > max) {
            max = integer;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

See what I did?  I added some extra logic to the loop to deal with the initial case<sup>1</sup>.

Note that this will return `null` if the set is empty.

An alternative would be to initialize `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and get rid of the `null` test.  For an empty set, that will return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Yet another way would be this clunky version.  This avoids the null checks, and at same time avoids the cost of creating the iterator twice:

```
Integer getMax(Set<Integer> set) {
    Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("empty set");
    }
    Integer max = it.next();
    while (it.hasNext) {
        Integer integer = it.next();
        if (integer > max) {
            max = integer;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

But I don't like it.

Finally, if you value correctness / conciseness over efficiency:

```
OptionalInt getMax(Set<Integer> set) {
    return set.stream().max();
}
```

Simple, clean, and you don't have to worry about the caller misinterpreting the empty set case.  (The caller can choose to use `orElse` to use a default value, test using `isPresent` or assert that the set is non-empty by using `getAsInt`.)

This can be generalized using `Optional<T> Stream<T>.max(Comparator<T>)`

---

<sup>1 - I wouldn't expect any performance impact here.  Under the hood, the `integer > max` test will be doing a null test on `integer`.  The optimizer should notice that we have two null tests on the same object and optimize one of them away.  This shouldn't even impact on branch prediction.  In most scenarios the predictor should bias towards the not-null path.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to get the maximum from a `Set<Integer>`, don't you?

You can have that using **Java 8** or higher along with streaming:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // samples are an empty set and one with ints inside
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Integer> emtpyNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(6);
    numbers.add(7);
    numbers.add(8);
    numbers.add(9);
    numbers.add(10);

    // select the maximum from a non empty set
    int maxNumber = numbers.stream()
                        .max(Integer::compareTo)
                        .orElse(0);
    // then do the same with an empty set
    int maxNumberFromEmptySet = emtpyNumbers.stream()
                                    .max(Integer::compareTo)
                                    .orElse(0);

    System.out.println("Maximum from non empty Set: " + maxNumber);
    System.out.println("Maximum from empty Set: " + maxNumberFromEmptySet);
}
```

For the case of an empty `Set` provided, you can use the `.orElse()` method in order to provide a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to do this:

```
Integer getMax(final Set<Integer> set) {
    if (set.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return set.stream().reduce(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Math::max);
}
```

Comment: There's a simpler way :-)